# How to read only one child key/value in Firebase?

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm building an app using the firebase database, and there is a part where I only want to receive certain properties of each user. Allow me to explain. Here is my data structure:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "JuBgk9ZjdrbP5fZVfmhdpF1FrjE3" : {
      "birthday" : 857278800,
      "email" : "*******@sas.upenn.com",
      "full name" : "Neil Doe",
      "gender" : "Female",
      "gender_age" : 220,
      "long bio" : "My name is Neilette, I wanna skoodlypoop you.",
      "short bio" : "Life is actually cake!",
      "username" : "Neildoe"
    },
    "QGqcGWCchCeFKQ6VTAgt9O2v3gs1" : {
      "birthday" : 926395200,
      "email" : "*******@yahoo.com",
      "full name" : "John Doe",
      "gender" : "Female",
      "gender_age" : 218,
      "username" : "Johndoe"
    }

}
```

Is it possible to only receive the full name and birthday of each user? Or would I have to pull down the full set of data? Or maybe I should structure my data like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007122/using-firebase-user-uids-for-keys-of-related-db-entries-good-or-bad-practice)?

I am doing this in objective c but an answer in any language would be helpful!

Comment: The Firebase client always downloads full nodes. So while you can read just the name of a specific users, you can't do the equivalent of `SELECT full_name FROM Users`. Also see my naswer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685610/retrieve-only-specific-keys-from-collection/26689437#26689437

Comment: Technically the answer is yes; you can retrieve the full name and birthday of each user if you know their uid. For example, *ref = usersRef.child("JuBgk9ZjdrbP5fZVfmhdpF1FrjE3").child("birthday")* then observeSingleEvent returns just the birthday of that user. You would need to have an existing array of uid's to iterate over to create the refs to the specific child nodes. However, as @FrankvanPuffelen stated and linked, in general a full users node would be retrieved. If you've got a LOT of data in each node, having a separate duplicate node with less data would be another solution.